# Can any one Explain how dalvik GC works or when does it kicks in

Tags: android, logcat, dalvik

DEBUG/dalvikvm(7485): **GC_FOR_MALLOC** freed 32760 objects / 1861208 bytes in 114ms
DEBUG/dalvikvm(778): **GC_EXPLICIT** freed 1136 objects / 57248 bytes in 70ms
DEBUG/dalvikvm(778): **GC_FOR_ALLOC** freed 1136 objects / 57248 bytes in 70ms

Can anyone point me why and when these starts to appear in logcat.

Whenever i perform 2-3 different actions in my app the dalvik gc starts, which makes me hard to read other logs.

Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GC_FOR_MALLOC** means that the Virtual Machine is trying to reduce the amount of memory as there wasn't enough memory left on the heap as it is trying to make room for new objects which are being created.

**GC_EXPLICIT** means that the Garbage Collector has been explicitly triggered because there wasn't enough memory left on the heap to perform an allocation for new objects which are being created..